# MAUI Pass data from AppCompatActivity

Tags: .net, maui

First time diving into Mobile app dev on .NET(MAUI) and have a couple of questions regarding "How to do" and "What is the best solution".

Q1 - I eventually implemented Google sign-in in MAUI application through dependency injection. I have GoogleLoginActivity(AppCompatActivity) on the Android platform that is getting data from Google API and manually deserializing it to a custom User class object.

Activity call from GoogleAuthService(android platform):

```
Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(typeof(GoogleLoginActivity));
```

Platform injection:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGoogleAuthService, GoogleAuthService>();
```

So the next task is to pass the User object from Android Activity to MAUI MainPage ViewModel or even to any other page in project (LoginConfirmation page for example). So, what are my options?

App deserialize `GoogleSignInAccount` object in override `OnActivityResult`, and call `Activity.Finish()`

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN)
            {
                Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.GetSignedInAccountFromIntentAsync(data);
                HandleResult(task);
            }
        }
        private void googleSignIn()
        {
           ....
        }
        private async void HandleResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> result)
        {  
                ....
                Finish();
        }
```

I've been trying shell navigation `(Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MainPage"))`
with an object in QueryProperty but it doesn't work (there is no QueryProperty in my code example).

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();

    try
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MainPage");    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("error", ex.Message, "error");
    }
}
```

Also as an option is serialize entire object to preferences, but I think it is a bad coding style and not sure that it gonna work.

Q2. Suppose, I have a signed in user and I need periodically keep and check some user data in my app.. What is the best approach to keep user data(ID, GUid, UserName etc) in the application. I imagine something like sessions in WebForms, but as far as I know there is no sessions in MAUI.

Cookies (is there cookies in the mobile app?)? Preferences(User object is too complex?)? Other options?

Thank you.

UPD: Silly me. Question 1 solved I did a rookie mistake and forget to change in App.xaml.cs:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

to

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

So even from `AppCompatActivity` i can do

```
 Shell.Current.GoToAsync("PostGoogleSignin", true,
             new Dictionary<string, object>
             {
                { "User", resultUser }
             });
```

and get user on the other side.
Thank you for answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without some code and a more precise explanation of what your actual problem is, nobody will be able to help you. Please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, make sure to provide code and other information as text and use the code formatting features.

Comment: By the way, is this Xamarin or MAUI? It cannot be both.

Comment: As far as I know, MAUI based on Xamarin and approaches from Xamarin could be implemented in MAUI. But I remove Xamarin tag if it's better.

Comment: Yes, it is based on Xamarin but it's still very different in many aspects and you cannot use both at the same time. It is possible to reuse and migrate existing components from Xamarin, but when using MAUI, you're not using Xamarin (except for some shared .NET functionality). For clarity, you should remove Xamarin if you're dealing with a MAUI project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the whole object/class as a navigation parameter.

```
MyObjectClass MyObject = new();

var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
     { "MyObject", MyObject }
};
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"/mypage", navigationParameter);
```

Then at your (mypage) code behind you will get the object into a new property myobject:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(MyObjectClass), "MyObjectNameString")]
public partial class GroupMatchPage : ContentPage
{

    MyObjectClass myobject;
    public MyObject MyObject
    {
        get => myobject;
        set
        {
            myobject = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As per your 2nd question, you can save the user's data into a simple json file and track all the process as needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're right mate. `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MainPage")` also works. Silly me forget to change `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` to `MainPage = new AppShell();` Thank you for your answer. You recon JSON file is safe enough?

Comment: Yes, the storage it's safe and a simple json is the simpliest way to do it. Thanks!